# Get count of element with value grater than quantile using boost accumulators

Tags: c++, boost, boost-accumulators

I'm using boost accumulators to calculate quantile probability.

I have an accumulator_set acc, and I get the quantile using:

```
auto q = boost::accumulators::quantile( acc, boost::accumulators::quantile_probability = p )
```

with p with the required probability, for example 0.99

I need to know how many elements are greater than q in this accumulator_set.

I can get the total count of elements using `boost::accumulators::count(acc)`,
but I cannot findout how to count elements greater than "q"

Does boost provides any way to do this?
If not, is it possible to implement an extractor like count, that can receive "q" as parameter for do the job? Any example to use as a base?

Thanks

Comment: There probably isn't a way to do this as accumulators don't record the elements, after you get q, you'll have to count the elements yourself

Comment: Can you show actual code? There is no accumulator_set (to refer to "how many elements are greater than q in this accumulator_set") and `boost::accumulators::quantile_probability` doesn't seem to exist (it does in `tag::` namespace). There are many accumulator features that seem to generate quantiles, which are you using?